# How can I find the file system usage of VMs only on particular devices?

Tags: vmware-esxi, powershell

I want to find the VM file system usage, but only on VMs that have a vmdk on a particular device.  The VM host could have storage from multiple devices, for instance EMC and IBM devices.  I only want to know the amount of space used by VMs that have storage on an IBM device.

I'm trying to use powercli to find this information, but I can't 'tie' the information together.  I'm not a VMWare admin, and so I'm having a hard time finding the correlation (and if my terminology is incorrect, sorry about that.)

I can find only the IBM disks with the following command:

```
Get-VMHost <host> | Get-VMHostHba -type FibreChannel | Get-ScsiLun -CanonicalName eui* -LunType disk
```

I can also get the file system usage with the following:

```
$AllVMs = Get-VMHost <host> | Get-VM
ForEach ($VM in $AllVMs) {

    $Views = $VM | Get-View
    ForEach ($View in $Views) {

        Foreach ($Disk in $View.Guest.Disk) {

            $disk.DiskPath
            ([math]::Round($disk.Capacity/ 1MB))
            ([math]::Round($disk.FreeSpace / 1MB))
        }
    }
}
```

However, how can I be sure that c:\ on host1 is on an IBM array and not an EMC array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer to this at the following link:

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/240466

From there, I was able to tie the VMHost and disk to the VM and the Guest information.

Answer (score 0):

The connection you're looking for is the datastore; each LUN on the IBM SAN is formatted into a "datastore" by VMware for storage of virtual hard disks.

Unfortunately, the [DiskInfo](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41/html/DiskInfo.html) object that you're ending up with has no information about which datastore it resides on.. which is kinda weak in my opinion.

I don't have a system with PowerCLI installed on to test this on right this second, but instead of enumerating `Guest.Disk`, try the `HardDisk` [property](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41/html/HardDisk.html) on the object returned by `Get-VM`.  Its `Filename` property should give you some indication of which datastore it resides on, even if it's just a unique ID.

Comment: Thanks for this information, using this I was able to find the link to the answer.